# TypeError: (0 , _auth.getReactNativePersistence) is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am getting this error when trying to use `getReactNativePersistence` in Expo with React Native.
`"expo": "^49.0.0"` and
`"firebase": "^10.3.0"`

This is my code:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };
```

Error:
`TypeError: (0 , _auth.getReactNativePersistence) is not a function`

I have tried both cases and it looks like `getReactNativePersistence` doesn't exist at all:

```
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
```

Answer (score 1):

There has been a change in firebase auth and they did some internal reorganization regarding how RN code is organized.

Here is the [link with more information here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#authentication).

Add the following code into your RN project file for auth initialization. If you are doing native and web in parallel, include this init only in *.native.ts|js file.

```js
// Have to do ts-ignore as getReactNativePersistence is not detected by ts compiler with firebase 10.3.0
// @ts-ignore 
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});
```

Comment: This worked with my Expo environment.

Comment: Thanks for this!  This works for the error but my jest tests are still failing.. anyone got any tips on how to get it through jest?

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using firebase@10.7.1.

Managed to fix that error by changing imports as follows (note the '@' prefix):

```js
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "@firebase/auth";
```

Also read [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7584) topic and make sure that you don't use the EXPO_USE_EXOTIC environment variable.

My .env file looks like:

```
#EXPO_USE_EXOTIC=1
EXPO_DEBUG=1
```

Answer (score 0):

- The **error results from** a metro bundler problem handling the `.cjs`, `.mjs` etc. extensions common to dependencies.
- The **solution** is to your `metro.config.js` file looking as follows:

```js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

// What I had initially
// config.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

//Fixes
// config.resolver.sourceExts.push("cjs");

// config.resolver.sourceExts = process.env.RN_SRC_EXT
//   ? [
//       ...process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(",").concat(config.resolver.sourceExts),
//       "cjs",
//     ] // <-- cjs added here
//   : [...config.resolver.sourceExts, "cjs"]; // <-- cjs added here

config.resolver.sourceExts.push("js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "cjs");

module.exports = config;
```

- Play around with the **commented segments under the fixes comment** and see what works for you.
- If the above doesn't work or you need more info, check out the following:

  - [Link 1](https://github.com/thysultan/stylis/issues/233)
  - [Link 2](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/535)

### NOTE:

> `import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth"; as well`

- Dependencies I have:

> `"firebase": "^10.8.0",`
> `"@expo/metro-config": "~0.17.1"`

### All the best

Answer (score 0):

Updating in case someone is using latest versions i 2024. I found a workaround for this on this comment in this issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7584#issuecomment-1785705367)

```
//@ts-ignore
import { getReactNativePersistence } from '@firebase/auth/dist/rn/index.js';
```