# Jest Tests failing with TypeError: (0 , _auth(...).getReactNativePersistence) is not a function on Expo 49

Tags: firebase, react-native, jestjs, expo

Similar to the question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961682/typeerror-0-auth-getreactnativepersistence-is-not-a-function), I have upgraded to Expo 49 and now some of my Jest tests are failing with the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _auth(...).getReactNativePersistence) is not a function
```

For Jest tests, how do I make it so this error does not fail my tests?

The package.json includes the following relevant packages:

```
 "firebase": "^10.4.0",
 "expo": "~49.0.11",
```

With the following Firebase file:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it... Add the following in your setup file:

```
    jest.mock('@firebase/auth', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@firebase/auth'),
  getReactNativePersistence: () => console.debug('Initialized persistence ...'),
}));
```